# Whatsapp Business API HTTPS Certificate

Tags: aws-cloudformation, whatsapp, certificate-authority

We just deploy on AWS Cloudformation an enterprise WhatsApp API following the next instructions:

[AWS WhatsApp API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/aws)

So all works normally, and the deploy finished correctly, the problem comes with the option "SSL Configuration", we understand that the API creates a self signed certificate so we get the error on the browsers because of that.

The documentation says that we need to upload a certificate authority, but do we need to get one from a third party to avoid this error?

We are a little bit lost, any advice will be nice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything else in SSL, the answer is "it's all about trust" and "it depends (on who you trust)".

To get this error to go away you will [need](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/aws#ssl-config) to upload an ["intermediate CA"](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/root-certificates-intermediate/) including [a private key, certificate for the key, and the whole chain of signed certificates back to a trusted CA](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/https#retrieve).

In a default operating system / browser environment, the (root or an intermediate) CA must be trusted in the client system. This usually means having your private key signed by [Let's Encrypt](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual) or paying a commercial CA.

Comment: gotcha, so what happen with the configuration about the cname, if we want to use a custom cname and we can't change the configuration, do we?

Comment: in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/aws#ssl-config there's a callout "In AWS deployments, the SSL certificate is created using the load balancer hostname..." Because the API expects a CA certificate, it can create certificates automatically - I expect it will generate a certificate using whatever name is required.